# Accessing one class from another: Instance Member cannot be used on type

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm getting into Swift by using the Xcode Playground, and I'm following an online course regarding simple image filtering.

So far, here's my code:

```
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(named: "sample")!
let rgbaImage = RGBAImage(image: image)

class ImageInfo {
    let rgbaImage = RGBAImage(image: image)
    func getAvgCols() -> [String:Int] {
        var totalRed = 0
        var totalGreen = 0
        var totalBlue = 0
        var avgCol = [String:Int]()

        for y in 0..<rgbaImage!.height{
            for x in 0..<rgbaImage!.width{
                let index = y * rgbaImage!.width + x
                let pixel = rgbaImage!.pixels[index]

                totalRed += Int(pixel.red)
                totalGreen += Int(pixel.green)
                totalBlue += Int(pixel.blue)
            }
        }

        let pixelCount = rgbaImage!.width * rgbaImage!.height

        avgCol["Red"] = (totalRed / pixelCount)
        avgCol["Green"] = (totalGreen / pixelCount)
        avgCol["Blue"] = (totalBlue / pixelCount)
        return avgCol
    }
}


let imageInfo = ImageInfo()
var avgRed = imageInfo.getAvgCols()["Red"]!
var avgGreen = imageInfo.getAvgCols()["Green"]!
var avgBlue = imageInfo.getAvgCols()["Blue"]!

var modifier = 20
// IMAGE EDITING LOOP
for y in 0..<rgbaImage!.height{
    for x in 0..<rgbaImage!.width{
        let index = y * rgbaImage!.width + x
        var pixel = rgbaImage!.pixels[index]

        let redDelta = Int(pixel.red) - avgRed
        let greenDelta = Int(pixel.green) - avgGreen
        let blueDelta = Int(pixel.blue) - avgBlue

        let redModifier = Double(modifier) * 0.49
        let greenModifier = Double(modifier) * 0.25
        let blueModifier = Double(modifier) * 0.07

        pixel.red = UInt8(max(min(255, avgRed + Int(redModifier) * redDelta),0))
        pixel.green = UInt8(max(min(255, avgGreen + Int(greenModifier) * greenDelta),0))
        pixel.blue = UInt8(max(min(255, avgBlue + Int(blueModifier) * blueDelta),0))
        rgbaImage!.pixels[index] = pixel
    }
}
let newImage = rgbaImage!.toUIImage()!
```

So far, that works well. The last bit of code modifies the image on a per-pixel basis, and the end result is a poor-man's attempt at some sepia colour.

The problem, however, is when I stick the entire image editing loop in another class, like so:

```
class ImageEdit {
    let imageInfo = ImageInfo()
    var avgRed = imageInfo.getAvgCols()["Red"]!
    var avgGreen = imageInfo.getAvgCols()["Green"]!
    var avgBlue = imageInfo.getAvgCols()["Blue"]!
    func applyFilter(filter: String, modifier: Int) -> UIImage{
        for y in 0..<rgbaImage!.height{
            for x in 0..<rgbaImage!.width{
                let index = y * rgbaImage!.width + x
                var pixel = rgbaImage!.pixels[index]

                let redDelta = Int(pixel.red) - avgRed
                let greenDelta = Int(pixel.green) - avgGreen
                let blueDelta = Int(pixel.blue) - avgBlue

                let redModifier = Double(modifier) * 0.49
                let greenModifier = Double(modifier) * 0.25
                let blueModifier = Double(modifier) * 0.07

                pixel.red = UInt8(max(min(255, avgRed + Int(redModifier) * redDelta),0))
                pixel.green = UInt8(max(min(255, avgGreen + Int(greenModifier) * greenDelta),0))
                pixel.blue = UInt8(max(min(255, avgBlue + Int(blueModifier) * blueDelta),0))
                rgbaImage!.pixels[index] = pixel
            }
        }
        let newImage = rgbaImage!.toUIImage()!
        return newImage
    }
}
```

NOTE: Since I am using the play ground, both classes are in the same file. For clarification just take my previous code, and replace everything *below* class `ImageInfo` with class `ImageEdit`

I would need access to avgRed, avgGreen, and avgBlue, but all I'm getting is

> instance member 'imageInfo' cannot be used on type 'ImageEdit'

and since I'm a noob at Swift, I'm not exactly sure how to fix it.

Did I miss anything?

EDIT: Here's RGBAImage. I did not write this code, it is free to download to anyone who takes the online course.

```
import UIKit

public struct Pixel {
    public var value: UInt32

    public var red: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8(value & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = UInt32(newValue) | (value & 0xFFFFFF00)
        }
    }

    public var green: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 8) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 8) | (value & 0xFFFF00FF)
        }
    }

    public var blue: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 16) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 16) | (value & 0xFF00FFFF)
        }
    }

    public var alpha: UInt8 {
        get {
            return UInt8((value >> 24) & 0xFF)
        }
        set {
            value = (UInt32(newValue) << 24) | (value & 0x00FFFFFF)
        }
    }
}

public struct RGBAImage {
    public var pixels: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>

    public var width: Int
    public var height: Int

    public init?(image: UIImage) {
        guard let cgImage = image.CGImage else { return nil }

        // Redraw image for correct pixel format
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue

        width = Int(image.size.width)
        height = Int(image.size.height)
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel>.alloc(width * height)

        guard let imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo) else { return nil }
        CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: image.size), cgImage)

        pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Pixel>(start: imageData, count: width * height)
    }

    public func toUIImage() -> UIImage? {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue

        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        let imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreateWithData(pixels.baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, nil, nil)

        guard let cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContext) else {return nil}
        let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)

        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: did you also import UIKit?

Comment: post the RGBAImage class please

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, it's at the very top.

Comment: I saw it at the top of playground, but not at the top of the class you posted after, that's why I asked.  how are you calling `imageInfo`,  if you are doing `ImageEdit.imageInfo`,  that will not work,  you would have to do something like `let imageEdit = ImageEdit(); imageEdit.imageInfo......`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the attribute `imageInfo` inside the `ImageEdit` before initialising the class.

It is only when the initialisation is called that everything becomes something. So `avgRed` can't get values from a function of `imageInfo` because it has not been constructed yet.

Doing this inside a function (`init()` is basically a function) is just find. Doing this inside a class doesn't work.

This does not work :

```
class A {

    let attribute : Int = 0

    init() {

    }

}

class B {

    let attributeA = A()
    let attributeB = attributeA.attribute // this is your problem

}
```

---

This does :

For all the attributes that rely on other attributes to be constructed, you use a **late init**. All the attributes that rely on external input, failable functions,... you declare as an **optional**.

- Late init : `var / let attrName : Type`
- Optional : `var / let attrName : Type ? / !`

---

```
class B {

    let attributeA = A()
    let attributeB : Int
    var attributeC : Int?

    init () {
        attributeB = attributeA.attribute
        attributeC = somethingOptional()
    }
    func somethingOptional() -> Int? {
        return 0 // not really optional, but just illustration
    }
}
```

So for you it would be something like this :

```
class ImageEdit {

    let imageInfo = ImageInfo()
    let dict : [String:Int]

    init () {

        dict = imageInfo.getAvgCols()

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. From your code, how do I access `dict`? Adding, say, `avgRed = dict["Red"]` outside the init gets me the same `Instance member 'dict' cannot be used on type 'ImageEdit'`

Comment: @zack_falcon that was just an example. Basically you do a late init for all the attributes you want for the class, or you declare then as an optional. This is done like this : `var / let attrName : Type` or as an optional `var / let attrName : Type?` Inside the init function you assign the values.

Comment: It's working as intended now. Thanks for the additional info, really helped.

Comment: @zack_falcon happy to help. Have fun with Swift :)